# In "Divergent" how is it possible there are so few divergent people and that everyone is born to follow a single trait?

Tags: divergent

In the novel *Divergent* by Veronica Roth, people are sorted into five “factions.” The factions are **Dauntless** (the brave), **Amity** (the kind), **Erudite** (the intelligent), **Abnegation** (the selfless), and **Candor** (the honest).

Knowing this, how come so few people are Divergent to at least some degree? Can people not be both honest and kind?  I feel as if there should be more Divergent people as no one perfectly fits the description of one of these factions.

Comment: Warning: Massive spoilers ahead; https://divergent.fandom.com/wiki/Bureau_of_Genetic_Welfare

Comment: This is explained at the end of *Insurgent* and becomes a major plot point in *Allegiant*.

Comment: A bit of a more out-of-universe answer, since it sounds like this is messing with your suspension of disbelief - people can certainly a) value one trait over others, even other traits they have, and/or b) people can certainly conform to single-trait-focused ideals and stereotypes if they really, really think they should.  Culture enforces a lot of conformity.  Divergents then would be those few who both cannot comply, and cannot hide their noncompliance.